# execve() and sharing file descriptors

Tags: c, operating-system

I read from man pages of execve that if a process(A) call execve, the already opened file descriptors are copied to the new process(B).

Two possiblities arise here :-

1) Does it mean that a new file descriptor table is created for process B, the entries to which are copied from older file descriptor table of process A

2) Or process B gets the file descriptor table of process A as after execve process A will cease to exist and the already opened files could only be closed from process B, if it gets the file descriptor table of process A.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which one is correct?

#2

Though what you ask is more of OS implementation details and that is rarely if ever important to applications, completely transparent to the applications and depends on the OS.

It is normally said that the new process *inherits* file descriptors. Except those having FD_CLOEXEC flag set, obviously.

Even in case of #1, if we would presume that for some short time both process A and B are in memory (not really, that's fork() territory) copying of the fd table would be OK. Since process A would be terminated (by the exec()) all its file descriptors would be close()d. And that would have no effect on the already-copied file descriptors in the process B. File descriptors are like pointers to the corresponding kernel structure containing actual information about what the file descriptor actually points to. Copying the fd table doesn't make copies of the underlying structures - it copies only the pointers. The kernel structure contains reference counter (required to implement the fork()) which is incremented when copy is made and thus knows how many processes are using it. Calling close() on file descriptor first of all does decrement of the reference counter. And only if the counter goes to zero (no more processes are using the structure) only then OS actually closes the underlying file/socket/pipe/etc. (But obviously even if inside of the kernel two processes are present for some short time simultaneously, user space applications can't see that since the new process after exec() also inherits the PID of the original process.)

Comment: The second paragraph is the best ("_inherits_" file descriptors). I get lost reading into the final paragraph.

Answer (score 22):

`execve` does not create a new process. It replaces the calling process's program image, memory space, etc. with new ones based on an executable file from the filesystem. The file descriptor table is modified by closing any descriptors with close-on-exec flag set; the rest remain open and in the same state they were in (current position, locks, etc.) prior to `execve`.

You're probably confusing this with what happens on `fork` since `execve` is usually preceded by `fork`. When a process forks, the child process has a new file descriptor table referring to the same open file descriptions as the parent process's file descriptor table.

Comment: I think this is a serious limitation here @stackoverflow.com that although both the answers are correct but i can only mark one of them as green.

Comment: @Ashish Now you can upvote both of them. You might want to mark this one as the accepted answer now.